# How can I change cgroup memory limits in Redhat 9 or Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, cgroups

I have a docker container which requires 16GB RAM in order to run, plus some extra from some processes it starts. The memory consumption on the machine seems to peak at 60-70% from total memory (64GB). However, it seems that `cgroup` is killing the process at this point:

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 2552559 (wi) total-vm:75308048kB, anon-rss:16499856kB, file-rss:2192kB, shmem-rss:83876kB, UID:0 pgtables:36892kB oom_score_adj:0
```

I haven't done any configuration of `cgroups`, so I have no idea where it takes the default values from and how can I modify them. Any idea how can I increase these memory limits or scrap them all together?

Tried looking in various sources, but I can't find a memory limit set anywhere.